# Custom authorization in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, security, identity

I'm developing a WPF application with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.

I need to implement security module to enable users to sign-in into the app. These users will have roles, and I'm going to use these roles to enable or disable functionalities on the app.

I will need also to connect to Active Directory to use its users on my app. That users will also use the app's roles.

I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Is there a framework to that on .NET?

I have found ASP.NET Identity, but I think I can use it in a WPF application.

I'm not good in English and I don't know how to name this kind of framework to search it on Google.

I have found something interesting in [Custom authorization in WPF](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/) article.

Comment: Such approach doesn't make much sense in a desktop app. The user is authenticated by the OS, roles are also assigned based on AD. This means that by asking about thread's current principal you will get all the information. However, if your app tries to restrict the the access to some resources programatically but these resources are still accessible for the user beside the app, you don't really have any security. In other words, resource level security should be done independent of your app, with ACLs and other available means.

Comment: I have to all that I have explained in a desktop app because 99% the machine running the app it isn't inside a Domain. And the AD is only used to authenticate users to it, not to manage roles in the app.

Comment: A hint question: how are you going to store the authorization (roles) information so that the app reads it but users can't alter it?

Comment: In a encrypted database.

Comment: This opens up a lot of specific questions on what kind of encryption you are going to use (symmetric vs asymmetric) and where keys will be stored. The implementation of a possible approach would dramatically differ depending on your answers. This is why I don't think you find anything ready to use. Rather, you are on your own.

Comment: Ok. That is what I'm asking for.

Comment: The question is too general at the moment. You'd have to elaborate on how you imagine managing the authorization. In particular, there is a workstation, a user and this encrypted database. How the database got into the workstation? Do you plan some admins to also use the same app on the same workstation to setup the app in advance? Or rather, the database is a part of app distribution and this is you, the license owner, who setup the database in advance and users just read it. Or maybe something yet different? Without this important background, there are no answers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood your comments but I'm asking about it there is a framework to manage users and roles in a WPF.

Comment: There isn't, I hoped it was clear from the very beginning of this chat. I also tried to explain what requirements you'd have to provide to start thinking of a possible specific solution. You definitely expect a simple answer but I am afraid there are no simple answers here.